# In cuBLAS, how do I get or set matrix element from host?

Tags: cuda, cublas

Hi I am using cuBLAS to do some matrix operations.

Occasionally, I need to get or set individual matrix elements.
As per cuBLAS documentation, the matrix is allocated like this:

```
    cudaMalloc((void**)&pArrayDev,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols);        
    cublasSetMatrix(numRows,numCols,sizeof(float),pArray,numRows,pArrayDev,numRows);
```

Now, if I need to change just one element, can I use something like cudaMemset? What is the right way to do this **from host code**? I don't want to copy the whole array from host to device each time I change just one element.

Answer (score 1):

[cudaMemset](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee) would be inconvenient to use because it only operates on bytes, so you'd be setting every byte of a `float` value to the same number.  That's probably not what you want.

But [cublasSetMatrix](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_5_9) already has the capability to do a tiled copy.  This could serve your purpose, assuming you have a host copy of the matrix originally.  Simply update the corresponding position in the host copy, then do a `cublasSetMatrix` call with rows = 1, cols = 1, and and the A and B matrix pointers pointing to the element to update in the source and destination matrices:

```
cublasSetMatrix(1,1,sizeof(float),&pArray[offset],numRows,&pArrayDev[offset],numRows);
```

If you didn't have a host copy of the matrix sitting around, you could do something similar with [cudaMemcpy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741):

```
float updateval = 100.0f;  // or whatever value you want 
cudaMemcpy(&pArrayDev[offset], &updateval, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

You can reverse the above operations if you want to retrieve a single element from the device to the host (e.g. use cublasGetMatrix, or cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, etc.)